# Adding "_old" to a file name

Tags: java, file-system

This is a trivial problem. The reason I'm here is to get a better idea of how to use Java's numerous APIs for working with files, folders, and paths. I'm hoping this specific example will help.

**Problem Statement**

I want to rename a file like this:

> /path/to/myFile.txt

to this:

> /path/to/myFile_old.txt

**Ugly Solution**

I've been trying to find a concise way to do this, and this is the best I can come up with:

```
Files.move(
        Paths.get(file),
        Paths.get("/" + FilenameUtils.getPath(file) + FilenameUtils.getBaseName(file) + "_old" + FilenameUtils.getExtension(file)));
```

It works, which is why I'm not on Stack Overflow, but

1. It's not portable because of the hardcoded "/".
2. It's really cumbersome -- specifically I don't like how verbose `org.apache.commons.io.FilenameUtils` is, and how I have to convert my `String`s to `Path`s with `Paths.get`.

I've looked at using `java.io.File` or `java.nio.file.Paths.resolve...` but I haven't found anything tidy.

Comment: I'm on mobile, so I can't write an answer, but I can give a hint: Look at the `` class. It's got all sorts of neat features for modifying file names.

Comment: It kinda sounds like rather than renaming the files, you should use [version control](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control) instead.

Comment: ...Mobile decided to cut out `Path`. Really sorry about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think that the approach of the question lacks only a better usage of the API of `java.nio.file.Path`.

Using the old `java.io.File` seems very ugly nowadays, when we have `java.nio.*`, where all the stuff like file separators is supported much better.

```
// ...
String originalFile = "/path/to/myFile.txt";
Path originalPath = Paths.get(originalFile);
String backupFileName = buildBackupFileName(originalPath.getFileName().toString());
Path backupPath = originalPath.getParent().resolve(backupFileName);
Files.move(originalPath, backupPath); // add options if necessary
// ...

private static String buildBackupFileName(String fileName) {
  String backupSuffix = "_old"; // or move it in a static constant 
  int lastDotIndex = fileName.lastIndexOf(".");
  if (lastDotIndex > -1) {
    return fileName.substring(0, lastDotIndex) + backupSuffix + fileName.substring(lastDotIndex);
  }
  return fileName + backupSuffix;
}
```

Other ways to build the backup file name: use `StringBuilder` or `String.format`, with or without the above `FilenameUtils`.

Answer (score 2):

1. Well, the first thing that's bad is the the fact that everything is crammed on one line. Max line character count is usually 80.
2. To handle the hardcoded `/`, you can use `File.separator`. (You don't need it anyways for my solution.)
3. You don't need to use `move()`; instead, assuming `file` is a `File` object, you can use `renameTo()`.
4. The thing that makes this so hard is the fact that `String` does not have an `insert()` method. Instead, we use `StringBuilder`'s `insert()` method, which is better than what you have up there.
5. Continuing from point 4, don't use `FilenameUtils` (I don't even know what that is). Instead, use `File`, and its methods.

After all the suggested edits:

```
private static final String _OLD = "_old";

private String getNewFilename(File file, String tag) {
    String path = file.getPath();
    String[] nameAndExtension = file.getName().split("\\."); // extension after .
    if (nameAndExtension.length == 1) { // no extension
        return path;
    }
    return new StringBuilder(path).insert(path.length() - 
            nameAndExtension[1].length(), tag).toString();
}

public void appendOldTagToFile(File file) {
    file.renameTo(new File(getNewFilename(file, _OLD)));
}
```

Yes, it looks longer, but it is more understandable (IMO) than yours, and does not require as much String concatenation.

Since `file` is a String, you can call it like so:

```
appendOldTagToFile(new File(file));
```

Or you can change the method:

```
private static final String _OLD = "_old";

private String getNewFilename(String filePath) {
    String result = filePath.replaceFirst("\\.", "." + _OLD);
    if (filePath.length == result.length) { // no extension
        return result + _OLD;
    }
    return result;
}
```

This method does not need anything from `java.io` or `java.nio`, as it only uses `String`.

Comment: According to the Javadocs of [`Paths`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Paths.html) and [`FilenameUtils`](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-io/javadocs/api-2.4/org/apache/commons/io/FilenameUtils.html#getPath(java.lang.String)), `file` is a `String`.